# Parsing Multiline Text in YAML: Preserving Newlines for Custom Document Rendering

Tags: syntax, yaml, indentation

I'm working on a YAML configuration file for a custom document rendering tool, and I need to include multiline text fields that preserve the original formatting, including newlines and indentation. However, when I try to represent the multiline text in YAML, it seems to lose the line breaks and indentation, making it difficult to render the document correctly.

Here's an example of the YAML structure I'm using:

```
document:
  title: "My Document"
  content: |
    This is the first para.
    This is the second para, and it contains some important details.

    This is the third para, which should be indented properly in the final document.

  author: "Authore"
```

In my custom rendering process, I need to maintain the exact formatting of the content field as it appears in the YAML file when generating the document.

I've tried using the literal block scalar (|) to represent multiline text, but it doesn't seem to preserve the line breaks and indentation as expected.

Does anyone have experience with parsing and preserving multiline text in YAML for custom document rendering? Are there any specific YAML configurations or additional syntax I should use to achieve the desired output? Any insights or code examples would be highly appreciated!

Thank you for your help in advance!